# How to assign value to pointer?

Tags: c++

I need to assign value to pointer, here is an example:

```
void foo(BaseClass * item)
{
    BaseClass * tmp = new Child();
    item = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    BaseClass * item = nullptr;
    foo(item);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that after a call `foo()`, `item` should be assigned, but it doesn't

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason to use pointers? Why not plain objects? If you *really* need to use pointers, use a *smart* pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: It's the same situation as `void foo(int x) { x = 2; } int main() { int a = 0; foo(a); }`. There is nothing special about pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`item` is declared as pass-by-value. It's a copy of argument, any modification on it (the pointer itself) has nothing to do with the original argument (`item` in `main()`).

You might want pass-by-reference.

```
void foo(BaseClass *& item)
{
    BaseClass * tmp = new Child();
    item = tmp;
}
```

PS: Don't forget to `delete` the pointer at last.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a *copy* of the pointer `item` from `main` to a different pointer variable `item` in `foo`. Any changes to `item` in `foo` concern only its local copy of this pointer. What you need here (if you really need this) is a pointer to a pointer:

```
void foo(BaseClass** item)
{
    *item = new Child();
}

int main()
{
    BaseClass* item = nullptr;
    foo(&item);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to use a *reference to a pointer* as well, but it's even harder to follow :) - see other answers.

Also note the following:

- `new Child` needs to deleted eventually - otherwise you have a memory leak
- passing *ownership* like this is dangerous and hard to follow (what I mean: `foo` creates an object, but then gives it away and doesn't care any more about its deletion)
- it's best to use smart pointers (see `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` for example)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the  item by value thats why  try passing it by reference

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You seem to be assuming that assigning one variable with name `item` (the parameter) would affect the other variable with the name `item` (the one in `main`). But since they are distinct objects, that assumption is wrong.

In order to modify non-global objects outside a function, *indirection* must be used. Simply changing the parameter to be a reference (which is a form of indirection) would make it behave as you expected. Another option is to return the value and assign the returned value in `main`.

P.S. Avoid using bare owning pointers. Your example leaks memory.